# ASUS ZenWiFi AX (XT8) fails to update firmware

Tags: router, firmware, asus

I have three ASUS ZenWiFi AX (XT8) routers connected in a mesh.

Two of them updated from firmware **3.0.0.4.386_42095-gcd938f7** to **3.0.0.4.388_23285-g5068da5** just fine.  However, multiple attempts to upgrade the third one, even manually, leave it at 386. The process does not complain; the firmware installed just does not change.

Anybody know what I can do to get this third unit to upgrade or what might be wrong?  The units were purchased long enough ago that they are out of warranty :-( ...

I have been doing the updates through their GUI interface to the units from an Ethernet connected laptop.

Addition:

The logs are mostly about devices connecting, etc.  There is this that might be relevant:

Oct 10 11:13:02 WATCHDOG: [FAUPGRADE][auto_firmware_check:(7058)]periodic_check AM 2:9

Oct 10 11:13:05 WATCHDOG: [FAUPGRADE][auto_firmware_check:(7088)]retrieve firmware information

Oct 10 11:13:05 WATCHDOG: [FAUPGRADE][auto_firmware_check:(7091)]user in use

Oct 10 11:13:35 WATCHDOG: [FAUPGRADE][auto_firmware_check:(7088)]retrieve firmware information

Oct 10 11:13:35 WATCHDOG: [FAUPGRADE][auto_firmware_check:(7091)]user in use

Oct 10 11:14:05 WATCHDOG: [FAUPGRADE][auto_firmware_check:(7088)]retrieve firmware information

Oct 10 11:14:05 WATCHDOG: [FAUPGRADE][auto_firmware_check:(7091)]user in use

The "user in use" part leads to a wondering.  In this setup, the unit that fails to update is the "primary" one, i.e., the one that is connected to the WAN (cable modem).  I can try swapping the roles of this unit and another one and see if it will update then.

Checking the serial numbers, etc., was also a reasonable thought.  The balky one has:

M21AHZ010572

The other two have:

M21AHZ010571

M21AHZ010203

I think this leaves the topological position of the node as the thing to investigate.  One other fact: The firmware update is from the original factory installed version (386).

Comment: Compare the units: what are the differences in *full* model number (including version)? In the settings? In the location in the network? In power supply?

Comment: Some routers expose logs - see if yours does also and examine it.